# why can not get the local IP with configparser in python

Tags: python, configparser

I run this python. everything is fine.

```
import socket
import sys
def get_local_ip(ifname):
    print type(ifname)
    import fcntl, struct 
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
    inet = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])) 
    ret = socket.inet_ntoa(inet[20:24]) 
    return ret
```

out put

```
<type 'str'>
192.168.1.250
```

But I tried to set a config file

here is my config file
socketConfig.conf

```
[config]
ethname = 'eth0'
```

here is the python code

```
import socket
import sys
import configparser
conf = configparser.ConfigParser()
conf.read("socketConfig.conf")


def get_local_ip(ifname):
    print type(ifname)
    import fcntl, struct 
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
    inet = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])) 
    ret = socket.inet_ntoa(inet[20:24]) 
    return ret

eth = conf.get('config', 'ethname').encode('utf-8')
print get_local_ip(eth)
```

then out put these error

```
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socketClient.py", line 28, in <module>
    print get_local_ip(eth)
  File "socketClient.py", line 23, in get_local_ip
    inet = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15]))
IOError: [Errno 19] No such device
```

Is anyone knows what is going on? thank you.

Comment: `print eth`. I'm assuming that it's not what you think it is.

Comment: @Shadow I tried. display 'eth0'

Comment: Try changing removing the quotes in your config file then - it seems like the quote are being picked up and passed along.

Comment: @Shadow thank you .it is working now.

Comment: Glad to hear. I'll write the configuration detail down as an answer. Please consider upvoting and accepting seeing as it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are being picked up as part of the configuration option.

Your configuration file should look like this;

```
[config]
ethname = eth0
```

Note the omission of quotes.